# How is a symmetric group the subgroup of the group of isometries of three-dimensional space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, isometry

So I have this question to solve. I've already shown that the group of rotations of a cube is isomorphic to $S_4$. I need to prove that these two groups are not conjugate when considered as subgroups of the group of isometries of 3D space. First off, I'm having a hard time figuring out how $S_4$ can be a subgroup of the group of isometries of 3D space. All the isometries in 3D can be represented as a product of reflections, so, this group would be a group containing the reflections in 3D. Obviously, I can picture this as $S_4$ representing the symmetries of a cube, but I don't see how that would help me solve the question. Could anybody give me some tips as to how to approach this question?

Comment: So you have an isomorphism from $S_4$ to "rotations of the cube". How are you supposed to consider $S_4$ other than as rotations of the cube? This question seems a little vague!

Comment: A cube has 4 diagonals...

Comment: @achillehui So if we consider $S_4$ as the symmetry group of the four diagonals, how would we show that $S_4$ and the group of rotations of a cube are not conjugate?

Comment: I'm not sure. The only thing which comes to my mind is  conjugation in $O(3)$ preserve the orientation, it cannot send a rotation in $SO(3)$ to a reflection. An exchange of two diagonals (i.e a transposition in $S_4$) can be implemented as reflection.

Comment: I recommend watching this video (the appropriate start time is embedded within the link) https://youtu.be/VSB8jisn9xI?t=44m26s

Comment: @eloiPrime I think I understand how the rotation of a cube is isomorphic to a symmetric group, but I'm still clueless when it comes to proving that they are not conjugate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the question is referring to the *other* faithful representation of $S_4$ in three dimensions, namely the group of all symmetries of a regular tetrahedron.

Comment: Could you use that to prove that the group of rotations of a cube is not conjugate with the group of all symmetries of a tetrahedron?